# I try to parse line by line within a text file in Python , but it just can parse first line, it can not read from second line

Tags: python, parsing, indexing, text, line

My Text file 'test.txt'  looks like;

hostname Switch

network 192.168.8.0 255.255.255.0

===================================================

My python coding "TextFileParse.py" ;

import os

f = open('test.txt', 'r')

while 1:

```
lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    item = line.split()
    print(line)
    name = item[item.index('hostname')+1]
    nw = item[item.index('network')+1]
    print(name, nw)
```

f(close)

The result message ;

hostname Switch

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\TextFileParse.py", line 15, in 
nw = item[item.index('network')+1]
ValueError: 'network' is not in list

How can I read the index from second line ?
I am not Program expert, just beginner.

Answer (score 1):

`f.readlines()` reads every line of the file at a time. You have the program searching for `hostname` and `network`, but both aren't in each line of the file. You could try:

```
try:
    name = item[item.index('hostname')+1]
    print(name, end=" ")
except ValueError:
    nw = item[item.index('network')+1]
    print(nw)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I changed python to your comment, still it does not work;     
import os
#print (os.getcwd())

f = open('test.txt', 'r')

while 1:
    lines = f.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        item = line.split()
        print(line)
        try:
            name = item[item.index('hostname')+1]
            print(name, end=" ")
        except ValueError:
            nw = item[item.index('network')+1]
            print(nw)  
f(close)

Comment: Thanks lwashington27,  modified codes a little, and it works !!         with open('test.txt') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        item = line.strip().split()
        try:
            name = item[item.index('hostname')+1]
            print(name)
        except ValueError:
            nw = item[item.index('network')+1]
            print(nw)